# python namespace hierarchy above object

Tags: python, namespaces

For example, if this code were contained in a module called some_module

```
class C:
    class C2:
        def g(self):
            @printNamespaceAbove
            def f():
                pass
```

then printNamespaceAbove would be defined so that this code would output something like

```
[some_module,C,C2,g]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make this code, as presented, have any output -- the body of g (including the decorator you'd like to do the printing) simply *DOESN'T* execute until g is called. I assume you do not literally intend for "this code" on its own to output anything, but rather intend to add a call such as C.C2().g() [which will actually do the output].

There's not really a very efficient way to do this -- you (well, the decorator;-) must start at the module level (which you can identify through the globals of `f`, the decorator's argument: its name is `f.func_globals['__name__']` and via its name you can look it up in `sys.modules`), then you must walk down every possible chain of names until you locate your calling function (e.g. via the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module in the standard library). Note also that nested functions are a particular headache in several corner cases.